# regex - name redaction

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to do name redaction project using python.  One of the pattern starts with 'by Lastname, Firstname MI @ time stamp' Sample string:

'Signed by Iam, Astuden T @ 03/17/2020 11:10:30 AM'

I would like to use regex to search for these names, and replace the names with asterisks.  Here's the desired output:

'Signed by ***, ******* * @ 03/17/2020 11:10:30 AM'

For the cases that does not meet this pattern, is there a dictionary of names I can use?

Comment: Please show us your effort and mention where you got stuck

Comment: What would your regex criteria be for identifying a name?  Couldn't you simply isolate the name using the usual python techniques (like Split, for instance), and replace the isolated part with asterisks?

Comment: Regex doesn't seem like the right tool for this, especially if you don't know it well.

Comment: There's no criteria for identifying the names, basically, all I will redact all characters that are in between the word 'by' and the '@'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> examplestring = 'Signed by Iam, Astuden T @ 03/17/2020 11:10:30 AM'
>>> re.sub(r"Signed by ([\w ]+), ([\w ]+) @ (.+)", r"Signed by ***, *** @ \3", examplestring)
'Signed by ***, *** @ 03/17/2020 11:10:30 AM'`
```

Regex: `Signed by ([\w ]+), ([\w ]+) @ (.+)`

Use https://regex101.com/ for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I was looking for.  I replaced the 'T' with a '.' so it will match any character.                                                                                                                      
Regex: Signed by ([\w ]+), ([\w ]+) . @ (.+)

Comment: Oops I didn't meant to put the T there. You don't need the `.`. `([\w ]+)` matches `Astuden T` Edited my answer